# Azure forget password link getting error how to i reslove it

Tags: javascript, angular, azure, azure-ad-b2c

Azure Active Directory B2C .I create user flow(policy's)for Signup/Signing.When i add endpoint url to my web application for Signup/Signing policy .When I click on Forget password? link it shows an error AADB2C90118 .This application on PHP and Angular technology.
Kindly help me how to i resolve it

Comment: Did you do a web search for that error code? I get plenty of results; please [edit] your question and explain why none of these helped and how your situation is different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the forgot password scenario yourself. A sign-up or sign-in user flow with local accounts includes a "Forgot password?" link on the first page of the experience. Clicking this link doesn't automatically trigger a password reset user flow.

Instead, the error code **AADB2C90118** is returned to your application. Your application needs to handle this error code by running a specific user flow that resets the password. To see an example, take a look at a [simple ASP.NET sample](https://github.com/AzureADQuickStarts/B2C-WebApp-OpenIDConnect-DotNet-SUSI/tree/complete/WebApp-B2C-DotNet) that demonstrates the linking of user flows.

Reference:

[Forgot password policy](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-javascript-msal-singlepageapp/issues/9)